# How to read zip text file?

Tags: python, word2vec

I am trying to read a zipped file (.gz) in python and I am having a trouble.

```
import gzip
import gensim
import logging
import os

logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO)

data_file = r"C:\\PythonProgs\\OpinRank.gz"

def show_file_contents(input_file):
    with gzip.open(input_file, 'rb') as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            print(line)
            break


show_file_contents(data_file)
```

I expected read the zip file but actually give me this error :

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\PythonProgs\OpinRank.gz'

Comment: That error message tells you that `C:\PythonProgs\OpinRank.gz` doesn't exist on your computer. Do you have the file name and path right?

Comment: yes I have the file name and path right and in the same place with my program

Comment: (Depending on file-system, case does matter in file names - for reassurance, please include a listing of *C:\PythonProgs\*z* in your qustion.)